# How to make a keyListener go back to previous key

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, key-bindings

so I have a keyListener, I finally overcame the Keyboard input delay. I now have a new problem, **When a user presses the "UP" arrow key to move "UP" they move "UP" for however long they want, then when the user presses the "DOWN" Arrow key, (*while* still holding the "UP" Arrow key) they move "DOWN".**

**How do I allow them to move "UP" again after the "DOWN" Arrow key has been released, without having to press the "UP" key again?**

**(NOTE: The "UP" key is pressed throughout the whole process.)**

here is the code I have currently use for listening for input.

```
private void keyListeners(){
    GlobalObjects.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            //Up    = 1
            //Down  = 2
            //Left  = 3
            //Right = 4

            if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
                System.out.println("UP KEY PRESSED");
                player.setPlayerMovement(1);
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
                System.out.println("DOWN KEY PRESSED");
                player.setPlayerMovement(2);
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
                player.setPlayerMovement(3);
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
                player.setPlayerMovement(4);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
                if(player.getPlayerMovement() != 1){
                    System.out.println("UP KEY released, but some other arrow key changed the playermovement to a different number (do nothing)");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("UP Key was a the last key pressed, therefore its safe to set player movement to "0" (not moving)");
                    player.setPlayerMovement(0);
                }
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
                if(player.getPlayerMovement() != 2){

                }else{
                    player.setPlayerMovement(0);
                }
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
                if(player.getPlayerMovement() != 3){

                }else{
                    player.setPlayerMovement(0);
                }
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
                if(player.getPlayerMovement() != 4){

                }else{
                    player.setPlayerMovement(0);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
}
```

If you couldn't tell, this is a 2D RPG based game. (if that helps at all, answering the question)

Comment: Can you please put sysout in begining of `keyPressed` method and check what kind of event is generated (if any) when you apply such user interaction as you described in your question? The most interesting part is when you releace down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I have found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042504/keypressed-event-in-java), it should solve your problem. According to official Oracle key events demo [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) when you hold one key, press another one and than release the second one, only releasing event of second one will be generated. I dont know why, but it is just like that. You will have to remember every pressed key and provide response for the leatest pressed one.

EDIT:
I have noticed that this is not and JAVA issue (at least, not only). According to documentation of [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), `KeyPressed` and `KeyReleased` are low-level methods:

> "Key pressed" and "key released" events are lower-level and depend on the platform and keyboard layout.

So such behaviour can be platform dependent. My curiosity lead me to try this actions on "Run" prompt (ye, I am working on windows), and guess what happend - same thing! Not only for arrows but for letters as well. When i press and hold eg. 's' than press and release 'k', while holding 's' I get text field input ending on 'k' like `sskkkkkkkkkkkk`.

Comment: Do you think keyBindings could solve this problem, because if I am playing a game (like Smite for instance) if I press "UP Arrow Key", then press "Right Arrow Key" I will move to the Right, but when I release the "Right Arrow Key" I automatically move forward (meaning that the "Up arrow key" is still registered as being pressed.

Comment: Yes I know what you have in mind, but please consider the fact that game engines are handling keyboard (genrally peripheral input devices) on lower level than swing does. You can try Keystrokes(keybindings). All you need in fact is posibility to aquire information what keys (plular!) are pressed ad current time, not just state change events like with listeners. Key bindings sounds reasonable. Give it a try